# qml CaptureSession freezes app on Android

Tags: android, camera, qml, freeze, qt6

I have a bug when using CaptureSession on Qt6.4, if I use it in a dynamic component, when I destroy it, the app freezes and I have to kill it.
This problem does not exist when I compile for Desktop.
I tried on Android 11 & 13, the result is the same.

Also it was perfectly working with Qt5 when only using VideoOuput & Camera.

I wrote a minimal example using a Loader, that creates the freeze. If someone has an idea to fix it :

```
import QtQuick 6.4
import QtQuick.Window 6.4
import QtQuick.Controls 6.4
import QtMultimedia

ApplicationWindow
{
id: window
visible: true
width: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth
height: Screen.desktopAvailableHeight

Loader {
    id: loader
    anchors.fill: parent
    active: activeBtn.checked
    sourceComponent: Component {
        Item {
            id: item

            Camera {
                id: camera
                active: true
                focusMode: Camera.FocusModeAutoNear
            }

            CaptureSession {
                camera: camera
                videoOutput: videoOutput
            }

            VideoOutput {
                id: videoOutput
                anchors.fill: parent

                fillMode: VideoOutput.Stretch
            }
        }
    }
}


Button {
    id : activeBtn
    text: "Active CAM"
    checkable: true
    anchors {
        right: parent.right
        bottom: parent.bottom
    }
}
}
```

The app freezes as soon as I unload the component, so when CaptureSession is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure the `Camera` is stopped before destroying the `Component`.

In other words, we need to acknowledge on some backends, the camera may be running in a different thread, and, we must make sure we give it sufficient time to terminate the camera and the corresponding `VideoOutput` preview before forcibly destroying the QML components.

We can keep your original property binding for starting the camera, i.e.

```
    property bool cameraActive: false
    Loader {
        id: loader
        anchors.fill: parent
        active: activeBtn.checked || cameraActive
```

So that will create the component as soon as the `Button` is checked, HOWEVER, during the initialization of the `Component`, we changed `cameraActive = true;` so that it prevents the unchecking of the same `Button` to destroy the component.

```
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    cameraActive = true;
                }
```

We use that Button event to stop the `Camera` with `camera.stop()`.

```
                Connections {
                    target: activeBtn
                    function onCheckedChanged() {
                        if (!activeBtn.checked && camera.active) {
                            camera.stop();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

As soon as we know the `Camera` has stopped with `camera.active === false`, then, we change `cameraActive = false` and that should resume the destruction of your `Component`.

```
                Camera {
                    id: camera
                    active: true
                    focusMode: Camera.FocusModeAutoNear
                    onActiveChanged: cameraActive = active
                }
```

Here's your complete code with all of the above changes. Note that I haven't been able to fully verify the code below, so, please treat the code as an educational guide only:

```
import QtQuick 6.4
import QtQuick.Window 6.4
import QtQuick.Controls 6.4
import QtMultimedia

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth
    height: Screen.desktopAvailableHeight
    property bool cameraActive: false

    Loader {
        id: loader
        anchors.fill: parent
        active: activeBtn.checked || cameraActive
        sourceComponent: Component {
            Item {
                id: item
                
                Camera {
                    id: camera
                    active: true
                    focusMode: Camera.FocusModeAutoNear
                    onActiveChanged: cameraActive = active
                }
                
                CaptureSession {
                    camera: camera
                    videoOutput: videoOutput
                }
                
                VideoOutput {
                    id: videoOutput
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    
                    fillMode: VideoOutput.Stretch
                }

                Connections {
                    target: activeBtn
                    function onCheckedChanged() {
                        if (!activeBtn.checked && camera.active) {
                            camera.stop();
                        }
                    }
                }

                Component.onCompleted: {
                    cameraActive = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    Button {
        id : activeBtn
        text: "Active CAM"
        checkable: true
        anchors {
            right: parent.right
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not fix the issue, even if I deactivate the camera when loaded and THEN I unload it, the freezes still occurs

Comment: @palador when you deactivate the camera, how about waiting for changes to cameraState and/or cameraStatus?

Comment: I wait a few seconds until the green LED on my phone is off, before unloading the component manually. So I'm 100% sure the camera is stopped. By the way I opened a ticket on the Qt bug reports site : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-110752